# Find an approximation of the unit ball as a weak-limit of a sequence in the unit sphere

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence, spheres

Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional Hilbert space.

It is well known that the weak-closure of the unit ball is the unit sphere. But I want to prove it as basicaly as possible, using the weakly-sequential deffinition of closure, by actually finding a convering sequence of members of B.

It is clear to me that $\overline S \subset B$ since $B$ is strong-closed and convex.

For the hard and interesting part, I figured out that I could pick an orthonormal basis for $H$,$\{e_a\}_{a\in A}$, and given a $x\in B$ write it as $x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \langle x,e_n\rangle e_n$ for $(e_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} \subset \{e_a\}_{a\in A}$.

Couldn't go any further.

Please guide me a bit, and let me know if you think that what I'm trying to do is possible. A nice hint would be welcomed :)

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have H.Brezis book? This is Example 1 on page 59, in which you could find a Basic prove.

Comment: @wisher: Thanks. I did check this book, and it doesn't seem as basic nor as explicit as I'm looking for. To be more precise, I didn't like the use of linear functionals, and rather like a proof using the sequencial definition of weak-convergence.

Comment: The weak closure of the (open or closed) unit ball is the closed unit ball. Not the unit sphere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $x\in H$ with $\|x\|\leq1$. Now define
$$
x_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\langle x,e_n\rangle\,e_n\ +(1-\sum_{k=1}^n|\langle x,e_n\rangle|^2)^{1/2}e_{n+1}.
$$
Then $\|x_n\|=1$ for all $n$.

For any $y\in H$,
$$
\langle x-x_n,y\rangle=[\langle x,e_n\rangle-(1-\sum_{k=1}^n|\langle x,e_n\rangle|^2)^{1/2}]\,\bar y_n+\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \langle x,e_n\rangle\bar y_n\leq2\left(\sum_{k=n}^\infty|y_n|^2\right)^{1/2}\to0
$$

Comment: Thanks @Martin. I understood the building of these $x_n$, but had trouble with proving that it weakly-converges to x. First of all, did you assume here that $(e_n)$ acts like the standart basis for $\mathbb R^\infty$? It seems that way but I can't understand why would it. Also, the last inequallity wasn't clear, but I guess it is a use of "cauchy-schwarz"?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm using $e_n$ to denote an  orthonormal basis, exactly as you did in your question. The last inequality is indeed Cauchy-Schwartz, coupled with the fact that $\|x\|\leq1$.

Comment: I wasn't very careful with the estimate, but the point is that we are doing the scalar product of a tail of $y$ with another vector, so it has to go to zero as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: I made a small edit, I was using $x_n$ for both the vectors in the sequence and for the entries of $x$. Corrected now.

Answer (score 2):

1. Let $\{e_n\}$ be an orthonormal sequence.  Show that $e_n \to 0$ weakly.  (Hint: Bessel's inequality says $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |\langle y, e_n \rangle|^2 \le \|y\|^2$.)  This is a very useful example to keep in mind when thinking about the weak topology.
2. Show that if $\{a_n\}$ is any bounded sequence of scalars, then $a_n e_n \to 0$ weakly.
3. Fix $x \in B$.  For each $n$, find a scalar $a_n$ such that $x + a_n e_n \in S$.  Verify that $\{a_n\}$ is bounded.
4. Conclude.